# On switching from NAT to bridge, have network issues in kali 2.0

Tags: ip, kali-linux, dhcp, network-interface, dhclient

Found few similar questions but none of them are answered so re-asking a similar question. I have a vmware 12, have kali 2.0 latest installed. 
First I try on NAT it works great but when i switch to bridged i am not given a ip so I try

```
dhclient eth0
```

and then too there is isn't  an ip given, I even tried changing /etc/netwokconfig but didnt help can someone put a layout of steps to fix this please, many users like me are still having this. Please comment to know more about the problem(any details)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware#Current_products shows that vmware hast many  products. When you write `vmware 12` what product do you mean specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Windows host, I found this [This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AsSDXznIhGc&list=WL&index=4) extremely helpful.